# Explode path to create multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, path

I am trying to make an associative array from a zip file, where the folders are the keys and the files are the innermost values.

Currently when I explode on `/` on each entry in the zip file I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Folder1
    [1] => Folder2
    [2] => File1.txt
)
Array
(
    [0] => Folder1
    [1] => Folder2
    [2] => File2.txt
)
Array
(
    [0] => Folder1
    [1] => Folder3
    [2] => File3.txt
)
```

To achieve that I am doing this (doing a `print_r` on `$path`):

```
if(in_array($content["ext"], array("zip"))){
    $zip       = zip_open($file);
    while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)){
        $zip_path    = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        $path        = explode("/", $zip_path);
        $path        = array_filter($path);
        $lastElement = end($path);

        foreach($path as $key => $item){
            if($item != $lastElement){

            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($files);
```

What I would like is for `$files` to contain a multidimensional array for a result that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Folder1] => Array
    (
        [Folder2] => Array
        (
            [0] => File1.txt
            [1] => File2.txt
        )
        [Folder3] => Array
        (
            [0] => File3.txt
        )
    )
)
```

What is the best way to achieve this without a depth?

Comment: Please clarify "without a depth"

Comment: Without depth, I mean an unlimited number of sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($content["ext"], array("zip"))) {
    $zip = zip_open($file);

    $files = array();

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        $zip_path = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        $path = explode("/", $zip_path);
        $path = array_filter($path);
        $lastElement = end($path);

        //reset pointer
        $cur = &$files;

        $count = count($path);

        //set pointer to proper parent folder
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
            $cur = &$cur[$path[$i]];
        }

        //add file
        $cur[] = $path[$i];
    }

    //delete pointer
    unset($cur);
}

print_r($files);
```

Comment: On this line `$cur[] = $path[$i];` I get `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? I think you could get that error if in for loop you say `$cur = $path[$i];` instead of `$cur = &$cur[$path[$i]];` or you missed the `$files = array();` line

Comment: yeah I copied it completely, the only difference I have is that my `$files` array above the if statement.

Comment: if I wrap an `if(is_array($cur))` around it then it kinda works where folders get added as files, and some files are missing.

Comment: Maybe I am not going about this the right way. Basically what I am doing is making a collapsable tree like this (Under the heading **Package Contents**): https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14147

Comment: Do you know which files are missing? Do a print_r of every $path and see which entry causes error.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to explode the path on the / and then use a forloop to put all parts inside a other array.

Then you can add an if(...) check if the current folder or file is already in the Array. if that is true, you continue, else you add it to the array and then continue